# Make a Scroll Event Occur Once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gsap

I want a scroll event to fire only once with the Greensock and jQuery libraries. I want to have my CSS transform consistently occur for each scroll over the `#aboutSection`, but I want GreenSock (`TweenMax.set`, `TweenMax.to`) events to occur only once

Here is the code I am using currently:

```js
$(window).scroll({
    topOfCallout: $("#aboutSection")
}, function() {
    var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (currentTop >= $(".webDevSection").offset().top) {
        $(".aboutSectionSkewBottom").css({
            'transform': 'skew(0deg, 0deg)', 
            'margin-top': '-90px', 
            'transition': 'transform 1s ease-in, margin-top 1s ease-in' 
        });

        var rounded = $(".roundedImage");
        TweenMax.set($(rounded), {    
            x: 670, 
            scale: 1, 
            alpha: 0
        });
        TweenMax.to($(rounded), 1, {
            scale: 1, 
            alpha: 1
        });
    } else {
        $(".aboutSectionSkewBottom").css({
            'transform': 'skew(0deg, 4deg)', 
            'margin-top': '-50px', 
            'transition': 'transform 1s ease-in, margin-top 1s ease-in' 
        });
        rounded = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Use flag variable to determine state.

Comment: The question linked as a duplicate explains the use of jQuery's `one()` method.  Although it is in reference to a question about a click event, it is still relevant to you question, hence the reason for citing it as a duplicate.